# Is there a good design pattern to execute 2 methods from different DAO in a single transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, transactions

I have two DAOs, InvoiceDao and InvoiceItemDao and i have the method `update` in each one.
This is the `update` method in the Dao:

```
public void update(E... es){
    Session s = null;
    try {
        s = ConnectDb.getSession();
        s.getTransaction().begin();
        for (E e : es) {
            s.update(e);
        }
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        for (E e : es) {
            s.refresh(e);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try { if (s != null) s.getTransaction().rollback(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        try { if (s != null) s.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method begins and commits/rollbacks the transaction manually. So if i need to update the `Invoice` and its `Items` using this approach, two transactions will begin and finish.

Is there a good way to to this, without having to create a method `updateInvoiceAndItsItems(Invoice invoice, InvoiceItems... items)`?

**UPDATE**
This is a desktop app, so, no automatic transaction management.

Comment: Use a Java EE container or Spring, that lets you handle transactions declaratively. It shouldn't be harder than annotating a service method with `@Transactional`, and remove all the manual transaction handling from your Java code. Spring **is** usable in a desktop app.

Comment: Additional to the previous comment: Use the design OneToMany/OneToOne relations so that the persistence layer handles this for you.

Comment: I agree with JB Nizet, use a service layer framework like Spring which has in-built transaction management facility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like `Commands` and a `CommandProcessor`?

http://wiki.hsr.ch/APF/files/CommandProcessor.pdf